# Efficient Way to Convert Calendar instance to java.sql.Timestamp

Tags: java, java.util.calendar

I am converting the `Calendar` instance `result.submissionDate` to `java.sql.Timestamp` as below, am wondering is there any alternative efficient way to do this by avoiding creating new `Timestamp` object?

```
invoice.setSubmittedAt(new java.sql.Timestamp(result.submissionDate.getTimeInMillis()));
```

Comment: You want to create a Timestamp without creating a Timestamp? That isn't possible. What is the problem in creating Timestamp objects? Why do you think you should avoid it?

Comment: If you are using a Timestamp, I suppose you interact with a DB - the time to create a Timestamp object is completely negligible vs. accessing the DB.

Comment: you can map the column to a Long and get rid of the middle man. but yeah big picture it would be surprising if the timestamp object was an efficiency issue; measure first, don't guess.

Comment: I recommend you neither use `Calendar` nor `Timestamp`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated. Instead depending on circumstances use `OffsetDateTime`, `ZonedDateTime` and/or `Instant`, all from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).